# How to add memmap(memory map) kernel boot parameter to a running android-x86 system

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-x86

I want to add kernel boot parameter that's 'memmap' in android-x86 OS.

Note: I do not have android device, but just emulation (using my laptop act as asus tablet)

- I have tried using Ubuntu's memmap addition but it did not work.
- I have also tried to find custom kernels but I did not get them for the target I am looking for.

What is the best way to config kernel,

- Do I need to built a new customized AOSP by setting up the memmap?
- Or just using terminal emulator app, adding the parameter. If this is possible then please elaborate how to do it using terminal.

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are really multiple questions here. Memmap is used to overwrite or add to the existing memory map. So if your E820 memmap table doesn't report the correct amount of memory layout, you could be on the right track.

Now, since you're running in an emulator it might just be a matter of increasing memory in some setting for the emulator. The emulator *should* report the correct amount of memory to the kernel. If not you will need to break the emulator in bios and figure out how memmap looks and then add memmap entries to the kernel commandline accordingly.

I can go into more details if you wish?

Comment: Please do, I am try doing using the terminal but failed to add the memmap. So now I am trying to add the memmap boot parameter in the BoardConfig.mk and building the AOSP all over.

Comment: Sure, if you could hind to me what emulator you are using? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html ?